# preciso de script para deletar dados do mysql com php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

gente preciso de um script php onde eu faço login e pega o id do usuario e onde pode alterar propriedades do usuario por exemplo:

tenho uma tabela no mysql com: USUARIO: TESTE, POSICAOX: 10, POSICAOY: 10.

o script pega id e verifica e entao muda os dados para USUARIO: TESTE, POSICAOX: 15, POSICAOY: 19.

e isso com a tecnologia de ajax que atualiza a posicao a cada 5 minutos com o settimeout do js.

se vcs souberem de um script ou um exemplo simples postem ai.

Comment: Não me leve a mal mas isto não é bem uma dúvida, é mais pedir que façam o trabalho por si. No entanto se tiver alguma dúvida concreta sobre Ajax ou PHP estarei aqui para ajuda-lo de bom grado.

Comment: nao amigo e pedir um exemplo, pois tudo que sei sobre mysql no google e estudo nao tem nada sobre como apagar dados de uma tabela e regravar , por isso disse se souberem postem um exemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva!

O script PHP para actualizar as posições do usuário pode fazer algo do género:

```
// Configuração da Base de Dados
// Nota: Tens de alterar estes valores de acordo com a tua Base de Dados.
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_NAME = "Test";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASS = "Senha";

// Criar a Connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);

// Update dos dados do Usuário
$pX= 15;
$pY= 15;
$idUsuario = 1;

$sql = "UPDATE NomeDaTuaTabela
        SET POSICAOX=?, POSICAOY=?
        WHERE idUsuario=?";

$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($pX, $pY, $idUsuario));
```

Relativamente à função Ajax para te ir actualizando os dados do usuários de x em x tempo não sou a pessoa mais indicada para te ajudar, mas com certeza que uma pessoa mais experiente do que eu te irá dar umas dicas de como fazeres isso.

Comment: muito obrigado helder ajudou e muito positivei vc